# Adding PictureBox into array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, picturebox

I am creating an array of picture boxes however I am unsure of the code needed to put the new picture boxes into the array.

```
    PictureBox[] bossHealth = new PictureBox[20];
        for( int i = 0; i<19; i++)
        {
            bossHealth[i].Name = "health";
            bossHealth[i].Size = new Size(10, 26);
            bossHealth[i].BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            bossHealth[i].Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 + (i * 10), 12);
            bossHealth.Add(bossHealth[i]);
            Controls.Add(bossHealth[i]);
        }
```

Comment: the line that is wrong is bossHealth.Add(bossHealth[i]);, just not sure what the correct format is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the code line `PictureBox[] bossHealth = new PictureBox[20];` You have an array with room for 20 picture boxes. However, every cell in this array contains `null` - you must initialize it in your loop.

Also, this line `bossHealth.Add(bossHealth[i]);` makes no sense. Arrays does not have an `Add` method, and `bossHealth[i]` is already a part of the array. Seems like you are mixing up arrays and lists.

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
PictureBox[] bossHealth = new PictureBox[20];
for( int i = 0; i<19; i++)
{
    bossHealth[i] = new PictureBox();
    bossHealth[i].Name = "health";
    bossHealth[i].Size = new Size(10, 26);
    bossHealth[i].BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
    bossHealth[i].Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 + (i * 10), 12);
    Controls.Add(bossHealth[i]);
}
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)